# C# How to exclude generated code from VS2008 code metrics?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, code-generation, code-metrics

How can I exclude generated code, like Windows Forms Designer related code, from Visual Studio 2008 code metrics?

I've been digging around but I didn't found any solution. `DebuggerHidden` and `DebuggerNonUserCode` have no effect.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the [GeneratedCodeAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.codedom.compiler.generatedcodeattribute.aspx).