# Exclude generated code from Scaffolded DbContext from Code Metrics Results

Tags: c#, unit-testing, visual-studio-2019, asp.net-core-2.2, code-metrics

I am working on a asp.net core 2.2 web api project. I have a separate class library called *MyProject.Db* that I have scaffolded the db context from an existing database. The `MyProjDbContext` contains an auto-generated method called

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
```

After some coding I had to perform some code analysis, so in visual studio community 2019 I ran the code metrics from the menu Analyze --> Calculate Code Metrics --> For MyProject.Db.

The code metrics results showed a very low maintainability index for the particular method and lowered the general percentage.

[image: The low maintainability index]

Since it is auto-generated code I want to leave it out of the analysis.

I have read some of microsoft's documentation regarding a customized configuration, such as [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/customizing-code-coverage-analysis?view=vs-2019) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/using-code-coverage-to-determine-how-much-code-is-being-tested?view=vs-2019) but these refer mostly to unit tests and they did not help me much.

I also tried 2 solutions presented [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39907175/exclude-class-or-method-from-code-coverage-in-net-core) but none helped either.

1. I tried using the `[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]` attribute but it did not have any effect.
2. I created a custom `[ExcludeFromCodeCoverage]` attribute and I added it in the runsettings file. But I got confused as to where I will use it via the Unit tests.

**EDIT**

According to this way [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/725660/c-sharp-how-to-exclude-generated-code-from-vs2008-code-metrics), even though it seems kind of old, if we add the GeneratedCode attribute in the class/method, it would exclude the code from the code metrics.
So the format is as follows:

```
        [GeneratedCode("Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools", "2.2.4")]        
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
                //Scaffolded models here
        }
```

As it turned out this is another failed attempt. The method was not ommited in the code metrics.

Is there a way to exclude  a method/class from a class library for this type of code analysis?